# Having trouble understanding the dynamics of this vs self vs nothing.

Tags: javascript

Consider the following chunk of code:

```
function Bar() {
    var _self = this;

    this.addPin = function (param1) {
        console.log('addPin');
    }

    function endPin(param1) {
        console.log('endPin');
    }

    _self.addPin(1);
    this.addPin(1);
    addPin(1);        // failse

    endPin(2);
    this.endPin(2);   // fails
}

var foo = new Bar();
foo.addPin(1);  // works
foo.endPin(1);  // does not work
```

From what I understand from playing with this code, the function declaration of `endPin` effectively makes it a private method to any outside callers.  While `this.methodHere` type of declaration makes it a public method.

What I am not clear on is the usage of `this` in the class itself.  `this` refer to the instance of the class.  Why, in that case, can't I use `this.endPin` inside the class.  Conversely, why do I have to use `this.methodHere` syntax when referring to `addPin` (which was declared using `this.methodHere` syntax).

Finally the difference between `this` and `_self` - I've read that _self preserves the original state of the class (or `this`).  How does it do that if it's a reference supposedly pointing to the same memory location? How is `this` different from `_self` in this particular example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Related: [Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked a lots of questions here, so lets try and break them down.

> this refer to the instance of the class. Why, in that case, can't I
>   use this.endPin inside the class.

Because endPin is not part of the class, it a local function inside your constructor.

> Conversely, why do I have to use this.methodHere syntax when referring
>   to addPin (which was declared using this.methodHere syntax).

Because addPin is part of the class, basically the reverse of the first question.  Doing `func()` does not automatically call the function of class.

> How is this different from _self in this particular example?

In this case it's not, but if you used `_self` inside your local function, it would capture scope so it's still pointing to `this` of the class, instead of the functions scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the this.endPin because the function is not defined in the class itself but inside a function.

If you write:

```
function Bar() {
    // do whatever
    this.endPin(2); // now it should work
}

function endPin(param1) {
    console.log('endPin');
}
```

Comment: This will only work when `endPin` is defined in the global scope, `Bar()` is called without `new`, and strict mode isn't used. Barring those conditions, `this` will default to the global object, permitting this. But, that's perhaps a rather fragile solution.

Comment: Yes I know, but he was asking so many questions that I was just trying to solve what I assumed was his main problem.